# How to recognize if input string contains any digit

Tags: c++

I have a question.

How to check if input string contains any digits?

Program:

`>> Whats your name?`

`>> Kam5il`

And if there is any digit like 5 program will ask you all the time for correct input string without any digit

This is correct string

`>> Kamil`

Answer (score 4):

`std::any_of` Checks if predicate returns `true` for `at least one element` in the range [first, last).

```
std::string name = "hel3lo";

std::cout << std::any_of( name.begin(), name.end(), ::isdigit); // print true since name has one number in it;
```